# how to handle nan in functions that should be used both for numpy and scalars?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm defining a function that I want to use both for numpy arrays and for scalars.

```
def inv(x):
    return 1/x
```

this gives back inf in numpy arrays

```
A = np.zeros([4,4])
inv(A)
array([[ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf]])
```

and errors with a scalar

```
inv(0.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in inv
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

To detect these zero values I can use numpy.where for numpy arrays and if(a==0) for scalars.

Do you know a way to write this that is good for both numpy arrays and scalars?

Thanks

GB

Comment: You can use nympy arrays of length=1 instead of scalars, such as `a=np.array(0.0)` which will give you `In[] inv(a) Out[]: inf`. This is a Matlab approach.

Comment: That's what I would like to avoid...

Answer (score 1):

`0.0` is not a numpy scalar, it is a Python `float`. Feed it a real numpy scalar: `numpy.float_(0.)` (or your prefered float type) and it will work as expected.

Note that `numpy.float_`, `numpy.float16`, `numpy.float32`, etc. are different from `numpy.float()`, which is equivalent to Python's `float()` (as pointed out by @dawg).

Inspect both with `type` to reveal the issue:

```
type(0.0)
>>> <class 'float'>
type(numpy.float_(0.0))
>>> <class 'numpy.float64'>

numpy.float == float
>>> True
```

More details here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.scalars.html, note the key statement:

> Array scalars have the same attributes and methods as ndarrays

Comment: You should emphasize that `np.float` and `np.float_` are different. `np.float==float` is `True` and `np.float_` is a numpy type.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question wasn't clear enough, but my main concern is to find a way to handle numpy.arrays and scalars in the same way.

Comment: @spec3, indeed; my answer is that your functions should expect or convert to numpy scalar types, which allow you to use any of the numpy functions directly. Try your function with `numpy.float_(0.0)` as a parameter... it returns `inf` as expected. I don't see another way of getting around the type issue, if you want it to behave like a numpy array/scalar, then it has to be a numpy array/scalar.

Comment: But my point is not to get 'inf' or 'error'. My question was:

"To detect these zero values I can use numpy.where for numpy arrays and if(a==0) for scalars.

Do you know a way to write this that is good for both numpy arrays and scalars?"

Comment: @spec3: To me, this is a case of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. What is the end goal? How else do you want to deal with the zero values in the input?

Comment: @Benjamin I'll try to explain you why I think it's not a XY problem. Forget about the zeros. Think that my mathematical function is f(x) = x if x<1, x^2 if x>=1. How can I write a function like this for BOTH numpy arrays and scalars? And I don't want to pass scalars as one element of an array. This is my X problem. if you tell me that it is impossible, well it's an impossible problem, no worries.

Comment: @spec3: Still not too clear to me, but the function you mention can work like this: `def f(x): x = numpy.array(x); mask = x >= 1; x[mask] **= 2; return x`, which will take for input any of: `3`, `numpy.float_(3)`, `numpy.array[3]`, `numpy.arange(12)`, etc. The only issue is that without more explicit type checks on the input, the output will always be a numpy array..

Comment: @Benjamin I think this last thing works great! At the end you can put something like if x.size; == 1 return x[0] else return x. If you post this as an answer I will approve it.

Comment: @spec3: I will not add it as an answer, because it does not answer the original question / title.

Comment: @Benjamin well, as I explained in the reply to the comment of the XY problem this one was the question, and if you read the text that I actually wrote as question it makes sense. I don't have anything more to add.

Answer (score 1):

Use `asanyarray` to convert the parameter:

```
>>> def inv(x):
...     return 1 / np.asanyarray(x)
... 
>>> inv(0)
inf
>>> inv([0])
array([ inf])
```